# java8 streams and state

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wrote this code, I tired to use streams here, but the implementation is hacky and using tradictional for-each loop would be better. is there any BETTER way to do it using stream ?

its very simple XML generator from two part path.

```
    input = "aaa.zzz\r\n"
            + "  \r\n"
            + "aaa.xxxx    \r\n"
            + "bbb.cccc";
```

output:

```
<aaa><xxxx>xxxx</xxxx>
<zzz>zzz</zzz>
</aaa><bbb><cccc>cccc</cccc>
</bbb>
```

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "aaa.zzz\r\n"
          + "  \r\n"
          + "aaa.xxxx    \r\n"
          + "bbb.cccc";
  List<String> list = Arrays.stream(input.split("\r\n")).map(String::trim)
          .filter(q -> !q.isEmpty())
          .sorted()
          .map(PathToXml::extracted)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
  list.add("</" + lastTag + ">");
  for (String data : list) {
    System.out.println(data);
  }
}

private static String lastTag = null;

private static String extracted(String path) {
  String[] paths = path.split("\\.");

  String tag = paths[0];
  String node = paths[1];

  String s = "";
  if (!tag.equals(lastTag)) {
    if (lastTag != null) {
      s += "</" + lastTag + ">";
    }
    s += "<" + tag + ">";
  }
  s += "<" + node + ">" + node + "</" + node + ">";

  lastTag = tag;
  return s;
}
```

I know I can convert it to foreach loop and make it less hacky, but maybe its possible to do it using streams.

Comment: Streams and state aren't going to mix very well.  Stick with old-school for-each.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I thought about it, but the only way to learn streams is to use it even when they are not best approach. maybe when I use it in weird use-cases I will find out some new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things I would change. First, your approach of path to XML conversion doesn’t look like it could be easily extended to more sophisticated use cases. Unless you will stick to two nested tags, you will need a class which can model a hierarchical structure which neither, the `Collection` API nor `Stream` API provide. The following generic utility class may be a starting point:

```
public final class Tree<T> {
  T value;
  Map<T,Tree<T>> sub=Collections.emptyMap();
  public Tree(T value) {
    this.value=value;
  }
  public Tree<T> add(T value) {
    if(sub.isEmpty()) sub=new HashMap<>();
    return sub.computeIfAbsent(value, Tree::new);
  }
  public void addAll(Tree<T> tree) {
    if(!tree.sub.isEmpty()) {
      if(sub.isEmpty()) sub=new HashMap<>();
      for(Tree<T> t: tree.sub.values()) add(t.value).addAll(t);
    }
  }
  public <R> R forAll(
    Function<T, R> open, Function<T, R> single, Function<T, R> close,
    BiFunction<R,R,R> combiner) {
      if(sub.isEmpty()) return single.apply(value);
      else {
        Iterator<Tree<T>> it=sub.values().iterator();
        R result = value!=null? open.apply(value):
          it.next().forAll(open, single, close, combiner);
        while(it.hasNext())
          result=combiner.apply(result, it.next().forAll(open,single,close,combiner));
        return value!=null? combiner.apply(result, close.apply(value)): result;
      }
  }
}
```

It is intentionally kept minimalist and not bound to a particular use case. To support producing a hierarchical structure from a `Stream` (e.g. from a path), the following `Collector` can be used:

```
public final class TreeCollector<T>
    implements Collector<T, TreeCollector<T>, Tree<T>> {
  T value;
  Tree<T> root, current;
  public TreeCollector(T rootValue) {
    value=rootValue;
    current=root=new Tree<>(value);
  }
  public Supplier<TreeCollector<T>> supplier() {
    return ()->new TreeCollector<>(value);
  }
  public BiConsumer<TreeCollector<T>, T> accumulator() {
    return (c,t)->{ c.current=c.current.add(t); };
  }
  public BinaryOperator<TreeCollector<T>> combiner() {
    return (a,b)->{ a.root.addAll(b.root); return a; };
  }
  public Function<TreeCollector<T>, Tree<T>> finisher() {
    return x->x.root;
  }
  public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }
}
```

The second thing is that if you want to use the `Stream` API efficiently you shouldn’t use `String.split` to create a `Stream` using the resulting array nor `String.trim` as mapping operation of something that is already the result of a pattern matching. There is `Pattern.splitAsStream` which allows to process the pattern matching results without storing them into an intermediate array.

Putting it together, the use case replicating the result of your question’s code looks like:

```
Pattern dot = Pattern.compile(".", Pattern.LITERAL);

Tree<String> root=
Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.DOTALL).splitAsStream(input)
       .map(path->dot.splitAsStream(path).collect(new TreeCollector<>(null)))
       .collect(()->new Tree<>(null), Tree::addAll,  Tree::addAll);
String xml=root.forAll(s->'<'+s+'>', s->'<'+s+'>'+s+"</"+s+">\n", s->"</"+s+'>',
                       String::concat);
System.out.println(xml);
```

Though the following would look more natural to me:

```
Tree<String> root=
Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.DOTALL).splitAsStream(input)
       .map(path->dot.splitAsStream(path).collect(new TreeCollector<>(null)))
       .collect(()->new Tree<>(null), Tree::addAll,  Tree::addAll);
String xml=root.forAll(s->'<'+s+'>', s->'<'+s+"/>", s->"</"+s+">\n", String::concat);
System.out.println(xml);
```

It produces

```xml
<aaa><xxxx/><zzz/></aaa>
<bbb><cccc/></bbb>
```

Note that you can use this code to collect path.strings.of.arbitrary.length.

Another advantage is that building the hierarchical structure works without sorting the entire stream which will be a great benefit if you have a larger number of path elements.

---

### Addendum

If you stay at the limitations of the original question, you can use a `collect` operation to create a `Map<…,Set<…>>` or `Map<…,List<…>>` to model a hierarchy of level two. In that case you can solve the task without additional classes. There are two ways to achieve this, using a combination of existing `Collectors` or creating an ad-hoc collector by specifying supplier, accumulator and combiner function.

Combining existing collector implementations (use `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`):

```
Pattern dot = Pattern.compile(".", Pattern.LITERAL);
Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.DOTALL).splitAsStream(input)
       .map(path -> dot.split(path, 2))
       .collect(groupingBy(path->path[0],
                    mapping(path->path[1], toCollection(TreeSet::new))))
       .forEach((p,l) -> {
           System.out.print('<'+p+'>');
           for(String s:l) System.out.println('<'+s+'>'+s+"</"+s+'>');
           System.out.print("</"+p+'>');
       });
```

Creating an ad-hoc collector:

```
Pattern dot = Pattern.compile(".", Pattern.LITERAL);
Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.DOTALL).splitAsStream(input)
       .map(path -> dot.split(path, 2))
       .collect(() -> new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>(),
                (m,p) -> m.computeIfAbsent(p[0], k->new TreeSet<>()).add(p[1]),
                (m1,m2) -> m2.forEach(
                           (k,v)->m1.computeIfAbsent(k,x->new TreeSet<>()).addAll(v)))
       .forEach((p,l) -> {
           System.out.print('<'+p+'>');
           for(String s:l) System.out.println('<'+s+'>'+s+"</"+s+'>');
           System.out.print("</"+p+'>');
       });
```

Comment: thanks you for a very good answer and explaining everything. there is something I need to learn. do you know how to do it without using extra classes ? I thought about maybe using groupby to do it. there is something I still need to explore. the whole idea behind it was to learn how to create very simple script for a very simple problem :)

Comment: @Pan Bydlak: I added the solution for the “very simple problem” which will work as long as you don’t extend the problem definition. After all, it’s not bad to be able to compare the simple but not scalable solution of a simple problem with the more complex but potentially scalable solution. Btw. additional classes like the `Tree` helper class can become utilities in the future which you will use without thinking about it just as you use collection classes today…